# What is the algorithm and underlying structure of this recursive DP algorithm about buying and selling stock?

Tags: c, algorithm, dynamic-programming

I have spent about 3 hours trying to figure this out, but I fail to understand two lines of code:

```c
b[j]     = _max(b[j],     s[j] - prices[i]);
s[j + 1] = _max(s[j + 1], b[j] + prices[i]);
```

The problem that the following code is a DP solution to is:
Best Time to Buy and Sell Stock

Say you have an array for which the ith element is the price of a given stock on day i.

Design an algorithm to find the maximum profit. You may complete at most k transactions.

Note:
You may not engage in multiple transactions at the same time (ie, you must sell the stock before you buy again).

Example 1:

Input: [2,4,1], k = 2

Output: 2

Explanation: Buy on day 1 (price = 2) and sell on day 2 (price = 4), profit = 4-2 = 2.

Example 2:

Input: [3,2,6,5,0,3], k = 2

Output: 7

Explanation: Buy on day 2 (price = 2) and sell on day 3 (price = 6), profit = 6-2 = 4.
Then buy on day 5 (price = 0) and sell on day 6 (price = 3), profit = 3-0 = 3.

```c
int _max(int a, int b) {
    return a > b ? a : b;
}
int all_profits(int* prices, int pricesSize) {
    int i, d, p;

    p = 0;
    for (i = 1; i < pricesSize; i ++) {
        d = prices[i] - prices[i - 1];
        p = d > 0 ? p + d : p;  // get it as long as it is a profit!
    }

    return p;
}
int maxProfit(int k, int* prices, int pricesSize) {
    int *b, *s, *buff, i, j, p;

    if (pricesSize < 2) return 0;

    if (k >= pricesSize / 2) return all_profits(prices, pricesSize);

    buff = malloc((2 * k + 1) * sizeof(int));
    //assert(buff);
    b = &buff[0];
    s = &buff[k];

    for (i = 0; i < k; i ++) {
        b[i] = 0x80000000;  // min integer
        s[i] = 0;
    }
    s[k] = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < pricesSize; i ++) {
        for (j = 0; j < k; j ++) {
            // profit on buy is current buy or last sale minus today's price
            b[j]     = _max(b[j],     s[j] - prices[i]);
            // profit on sale is current sale or last buy plus today's price
            s[j + 1] = _max(s[j + 1], b[j] + prices[i]);
        }
    }

    p = s[k];

    free(buff);

    return p;
}
```

I understand all of the code except for the two lines mentioned at the beginning:

- What is the purpose of the buff array? The buff array is divided into two parts, one with b and the other with s. From what I understand, s[n] is the max profit you can make on the nth day. I have no idea what b is doing.
- Why are we doing MAX of `b[j]     = _max(b[j],     s[j] - prices[i]);`, should the buying price not be the lowest? Why is b[j] the max of these two things? What is s[j] - prices[i]?
- This probably also has to do with the algorithm but why this statement: `s[j + 1] = _max(s[j + 1], b[j] + prices[i]);` What is b[j] + prices[i] doing in this expression and what does it mean?
- Why are we going through each day k times: `for (j = 0; j < k; j ++) {`?

I have spent a lot of time (3 hours) thinking about this solution and comparing it to other DP problems, but no luck. I compared it to longest increasing subsequence DP problem and how you're supposed to "Let length(k) denote the length of the longest increasing subsequence that ends at position k" and tried to apply that logic to arrays here, but no luck.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider that we would like to consider each price (or day) as either a buying day or a selling day to arrive at the best choices. The `b` list is considering each day as a `buy` day and the `s` list as a `sell` day. Now we just implement the logic. What might be slightly confusing is that because `s` is updated at `j + 1`, for the `s` list, `j` is the day before.

The best `k`th buy day for the price at `i` is either what we already have as the `k`th buy day or we buy, which equals the `(k-1)`th best sell day (that's the confusing `s[j]`) subtracted by the buying price since we just bought!

```
b[j] = _max(b[j], s[j] - prices[i]);
```

The best `k`th sell day for the price at `i` is either what we already have as the `k`th sell day or the best `k`th buy day (since a `k`th transaction has both a buy and a sell) plus today's price since we just earned it selling a stock!

```
s[j + 1] = _max(s[j + 1], b[j] + prices[i]);
```

#### Update

Per OP's request, here's an example: `[5, 20, 15, 100, 35] k = 2`.

```
b represents the most profit at
the jth buy considering prices up to i:
max(b[j], s[j] - prices[i])

s represents the most profit at
the jth sell (index j+1 in s) considering prices up to i:
max(s[j + 1], b[j] + prices[i])

note that when j = 0, s[j] (the sell before the first buy)
is always 0

prices[0]:
  j:  0     1
  b:  -5    -5 // max(-Inf, 0 - 5), max(-Inf, 0 - 5)
  s:  0     0  // max(0, -5 + 5), max(0, -5 + 5)

prices[1]:
  j:  0     1
  b:  -5    -5 // max(-5, 0 - 20), max(-5, 15 - 20)
  s:  15    15 // max(0, -5 + 20), max(0, -5 + 20)

prices[2]:
  j:  0    1
  b:  -5   0   // max(-5, 0 - 15), max(-5, 15 - 15)
  s:  15   15  // max(15, -5 + 15), max(15, 0 + 15)    

prices[3]:
  j:  0    1
  b:  -5   0   // max(-5, 0 - 100), max(0, 0 - 100) 
  s:  95   100 // max(15, -5 + 100), max(15, 0 + 100)

prices[4]:
  j:  0    1
  b:  -5   60  // max(-5, 0 - 35), max(0, 95 - 35)
  s:  95   100 // max(95, -5 + 35), max(100, 60 + 35)
```

Comment: I really want to thank you for your answer but I still don't quite get it. I know I'm supposed to be making abstractions when it comes to DP, but could you elaborate more and give tangible examples in your answer as to what you mean by the `k`th day (1st, 2nd, 0th?), and why "The best kth sell day for the price at i is either what we already have as the kth sell day or the best kth buy day " and "The best kth buy day for the price at i is either what we already have as the kth buy day or we buy," Sorry for the trouble, but I'm not sure I'll understand without concrete examples.

Comment: @herophant DP is a way to store and update results for overlapping subproblems. `k`th day in my description is the `k`th transaction - I hope it's clear that we can have at most `k` of these so we're just considering each, one by one, termed `j`, for each price.

Comment: @herophant Now say we're going along and at some early `i` we have a huge profit at the `k`th transaction, `j`. Now we have `s[j] = huge profit`. Then some time later, we're at a later `i` down the list of prices, and for the same `j` (the `k`th transaction) our sell this time, if we were to sell, would be much lower than the best we calculated so far (at the earlier `i` price). In that case, the program would choose to stick with our earlier choice for where the `k`th transaction should be.

Comment: @herophant you might want to write out the table yourself for a very short arbitrary list of prices, and small `k`, like 2. Follow the update logic, considering each price as a buy or sell for each transaction (obviously with some restriction since the first price can't be a sell or a second transaction, etc. Those can sometimes be easily handled in DP by referencing a constant in the table).

Comment: We're doing k transactions everyday, right, because of this: `for (j = 0; j < k; j ++) {` I'll do the table now (I suppose the columns would be s, b, k, j and i..)

Comment: @herophant `j` is tracking `k` so `k` is not needed in the table. Just watch how `s` and `b` are updated again and again as `j` is re-visited for each price (`i`). `j` is the `k`th buy or sell (1st buy/sell, 2nd buy/sell, etc.).

Comment: @herophant maybe I should have said `j`th instead of `k`th since our target is `k` and we are iterating on the `j`th transaction until we reach the `k`th. I just sometimes envision the target and the iterator as the same thing...

Comment: Here's the spreadsheet I've created: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jQBWpDPWzsmRuBdjNi4bQ_Y6-wNMCvdpKpCtuGuZNZg/edit#gid=0 but I'm not sure I'm gaining new insight (why are some b values positive? stocks cost money, not the other way...). By looking at the code and your answer more though here's something: `s[j + 1] = _max(s[j + 1], b[j] + prices[i]);` is true because by best sell day you mean the day on which we make the most profit, and s stores best sell day for each transaction. So, the max is either what we already have, or b(price for day) + money gotten. I dunno what b is still

Comment: @herophant answer updated. `s` stores the most profit we can make at the `j`th sell (indexed at `s[j+1]`), considering prices up to `i`. The trick in dynamic programming is that the value in `s` (or `b`) is storing the best profit after we have chosen whether or not the `i`th price will *or will not* be used as a sell. So if we had a better profit for the `j`th sell calculated before, `s[j +1]` would continue to store the earlier result for the `j`th sell (see example), indicating that `prices[i]` was not a good enough choice for the `j`th sell. (Similar explanation for `b`, see example intro)

Comment: Some questions: In prices[3], in the case of j == 1, shouldn't b be calculated using max(0, 95 - 100) since 95 is the last kth sell day's profit? Still comes to 0 but was wondering...     Also, isn't it wrong to use the same price twice? In prices[3] for example, on j == 0, we involve the price of 100 in our transactions and make a profit of 95. buy when price ==5, sell at price ==100... but the assumption is that we only had 1 transaction when j==0... yeah, I think I get it now. Thank you. I thought doing examples would help me learn, and I think this has helped considerably with DP.

Comment: @herophant `prices[3], j = 1` for `b` is the second `buy`, considering prices up to and including the 100 price. In that case, `s[j]` is the best `first sell` profit, which is 15 (remember that `s` in the code is indexed at `j + 1`, which is a little confusing). Then we subtract 100, which is the current price, since we are deciding whether it would have been good to buy here.

Comment: I thought that in `j = 1`, using `b[j] = max(b[j], s[j] - prices[i])`, we used `s[j] = s[1] = 95` because we changed it in `prices[3], j = 0` using this: `s[j + 1] = _max(s[j + 1], b[j] + prices[i])` which means we updated `s[1]` as `max(s[1], b[1] + prices[3])` = `max(0, 0 + 100)` So I still don't understand why we're using the old value

Comment: @herophant you're right. We seem to be considering the same day both for a sell and a buy. Are you sure the code passes the online judge?

Comment: Yes, apparently it is faster than 100% of solutions and uses less space than 100% of solutions. The question is "Best Time to Buy and Sell Stock IV" on leetcode.com if you want to try it out yourself (be sure to select C language before pasting code in if you're unfamiliar with the site)

Comment: @herophant well, maybe we're allowed to sell and buy on the same day as long as all buy-sell transactions are sequential?

Comment: Sure but that doesn't make any sense. Selling and buying, buying and selling, whichever order, if you do them on the same day you just break even, no profit

Comment: @herophant my understanding is that my example showed logic that only neglected the possibility allowed in the code for selling then buying on the same day. While possibly only useful in order to advance j, it does not detract or cause false logic. We can still observe the limited space used by overwriting the `s` and `b` lists multiple times for each price.

Comment: So, what is the answer to this question: In `prices[3]`, in the case of `j == 1`, shouldn't `b` be calculated using `max(0, 95 - 100)`? I was picturing `prices[3]` like this: we must buy, so we buy at the lowest price, 5, our profit is -5 `(b, j = 0)`. Now we sell that for 20. Our profit is 15 `(s, j = 0)`. Now after these transactions, we're permitted another. So our profit is `max(b[0] = -5, 15 - 100) = -5` (not 0?) `(b, j = 1)`. At the end, we sell the stock at 100. Our profit is `max(95, 100 + -5)` = 95 `(s, j = 1)`? Can you show why my logic is faulty in your answer? :)